Poetry: adding packages stored in Azure DevOps
I'm a bit of a beginner to working with Poetry and Azure, so forgive me in advance for any syntax errors and lack of terminology
I built a python package called 'npipack' stored in Azure DevOps: https://dev.azure.com/NPIDemandPlanning/npipack
Now, I created a local (I mean, locally in my laptop) python-based project where the dependecies and venv are managed by Poetry. I would like to add 'npipack' package inside the project as well.
Here the step I followed:

I set up an Enviroment Variable called AZURE_DEV_OPS_PAT where to store my private access token  I previously created in Azure DevOps. The PAT is not expired and the command echo $AZURE_DEVOPS_PAT returns the correct PAT
I set up the pyproject.toml file automatically created by Poetry and I added the following code

[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "azure"
url = "https://${AZURE_DEVOPS_PAT}@pkgs.dev.azure.com/NPIDemandPlanning/_packaging/npi-pack-feed/pypi/simple/"
default = false



From terminal I run (without getting any errors)

poetry config repositories.azure https://<MY_PAT>@pkgs.dev.azure.com/NPIDemandPlanning/_packaging/npi-pack-feed/pypi/simple
poetry config http-basic.azure <MY_USERNAME> <MY_PAT>


From terminal I installed artifacts-keyring via the command poetry self add artifacts-keyring
Finally, I run this command: poetry add npipack --source azure. Here is where I get an Authorization error

(base) (update sales & forecast report-py3.11) bash-3.2$ poetry add npipack --source azure
Source (azure): Authorization error accessing https://${AZURE_DEVOPS_PAT}@pkgs.dev.azure.com/NPIDemandPlanning/_packaging/npi-pack-feed/pypi/simple/npipack/

Here other useful information:

Machine: Mac M1 Pro (Sequoia 15.1)
Python: 3.11
Poetry: 1.8.4
PAT: the PAT has Packaging > Read permission and it's not expired. It does not contain any special character
Other Sources: Azure Artifacts and Poetry, Azure Pipelines and Poetry, issue #3344

Did you experince something similar? Could please help me to solve the Authorization error?

Hi there, By I built a python package called 'npipack' stored in Azure DevOps, may I assume you published the python package in an Azure Artifacts feed with pip?

By I set up the pyproject.toml file automatically created by Poetry so you published the  Python package with poetry publish rather than twine upload?

Yes, the python package is published in Azure Artifacts. About the second I used all the poetry commands like poetry build. However, I'm quite confident I've never used poetry publish (nor twine upload).

As far as I tested, we didn't need to retrieve the credentials stored in keyring when the poetry.source.url already contained the PAT in plaintext for authentication. You may test disabling it to rule out the cause by the PAT.
poetry config keyring.enabled false

poetry source add --priority=explicit azure https://xxxMyPATxxx@pkgs.dev.azure.com/<MyADOOrgName>/_packaging/npi-pack-feed/pypi/simple/

poetry add npipack --source azure

In addition, as suggested in the Poetry document, you may use environment variable POETRY_HTTP_BASIC_AZURE_PASSWORD to provide the credentials
poetry source add --priority=explicit azure https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/<MyADOOrgName>/_packaging/npi-pack-feed/pypi/simple/

export POETRY_HTTP_BASIC_AZURE_PASSWORD="xxxMyPATxxx"

poetry add npipack --source azure



So you could install my package correctly even if you do not have access to the page of the project? (which is also a private repository)

No, and that is impossible. I published the python package to my own feed.

@DavideMotta, so may I know if the workaround in my answer worked from your side?

Honestly, I still have to try. On Monday I will try to involve a colleague of mine to see if your guide works. In the meantime, thank you

Sure. Look forward to your good news and good luck with the works to go!

It worked really smoothly. Thank u very much
